# Connect a bipolar stepper motor to a breadboard

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, breadboard

I would like to connect a bipolar stepper motor, with a connector as the one in the picture, to a breadboard. Is there any adapter I can use?
[image: bipolar motor connector]

Comment: What you should ask for is help identifying what parts you need to build the adapter board you want. Personally I have no experience specifying ribbon cables, but surely someone here can point you in the right direction.

Comment: It looks like an FFC cable.  What's the pitch (distance between the contacts)?  What's the thickness at the tip?  What's the overall width?  These are the parameters that are usually sufficient for identifying a mating connector.

Answer (score 4):

When prototyping with a narrow FFC cable, such as this one with only four contacts, it is possible to add header pins directly without having to make a special PC board and all the additional expense.

You start out with a 100mil centers header such as this that fits into your particular proto board.

[image]

Then next thing is to bend the pins into the shape shown below so that they align to the center to center contact spacing of the FFC.

[image]

After the contacts are shaped as necessary you have to clip them so that they are all the same length.

[image]

This header assembly can be soldered to the contacts of the FFC cable. This process is greatly aided by use of a "helping hands" unit as shown here.

[image]

A close up will show how the header pins line up with the contact pads of the FFC cable.

[image]

The header pins will be soldered to the FFC contacts using a fine tipped soldering iron and very small diameter solder. A generous application of soldering flux will be necessary to get the solder to flow and adhere to the contact pads and the header pins. You want to try to minimize the heat applied to the FFC cable and let the header pins be what you heat up the most. If shorts occur in the solder process use solder wick to remove the excess solder. Here is what the solder joints look like when it is all cleaned up afterwards to remove the flux. (Note that is you use too high of heat or to big of solder tip you are likely to melt and destroy the FFC cable end). The picture here is proof that it can be done.

[image]

Here is the completed assembly showing the stepper motor with the header attached. This can now be directly plugged into a proto board. If the usage is expected to be over an extended period of time with assembly and dis-assembly it is advisable to use some epoxy to cover the contact area on the header and up a ways onto the FFC cable. I have found one way that works well for this is to bond just one side of the header pins and back side of the FFC cable to a heavier material such as a piece of heavy card stock, a piece plastic of a type that the epoxy will adhere to or even a piece of a popsicle stick.

[image]

I apologize for the poor focus of some of the photos. Smart phone cameras can be extremely fiddly to get nice clear closeup shots.

Answer (score -1):

I very much doubt if you will find a suitable adapter.

Design a small PCB with a connector for the stepper and four pins for the breadboard. It will only take a few minutes with one of the free PCB design packages such as Design Spark from RS Components. You can then get the board made very cheaply by one of the Chinese PCB suppliers such as ITead Studio. Of course, you will have to find a suitable connector for the stepper, as noted in the comments.